# streamgraph : a problem downloading this packkage : Windows 10

Tags: r, debugging, installation, package

I am trying to dowload the `Streamgraph` package but there is a problem.

I tried the followings :

```
install.packages("Streamgraph")

devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/streamgraph",force = TRUE)
```

the error I get (after executing the dowload and you think everything is going well)

```
Warning message:
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\2022aa012\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\digest\libs\x64\digest.dll to C:\Users\2022aa012\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\digest\libs\x64\digest.dll: Permission denied
```

to resume they say : permission denied.
appreciate the help

Comment: The install from GitHub worked for me.  What error do you get when you try it?

Comment: please check the updated version

Comment: Restart R and try the second only

Comment: did not work unfortunately. And I saw another warning that : Rtools that I have is not compatibe and that I need to download another version